According to YEC, how and when did the Americas become populated?
I’m aware that modern scientific theories propose an ice bridge which allowed for travelers to reach the Americas and that this fact accounts for the existence of Native Americans (and South American tribes, etc.).
However, it would seem to be problematic on YEC to propose a similar idea given that the ice bridge is dated much earlier than 6000 or 4200 years ago (4200 being when answers in genesis dates the Tower of Babel).
So what is the explanation for the human population in America, especially at the scale which it was presumably at?

We might have to wait for Moana II to come out


modern scientific theories propose an ice bridge which allowed for travelers to reach the Americas

This is a popular hypothesis, and if they're coming from Russia through Alaska, it's not even a great distance. IIRC there is even genetic evidence of this; I recommend checking into Nathaniel Jeanson's research. (You might try this video or this video.)
Another is that they arrived by boat. Noah (and his sons) didn't die the instant they stepped off the Ark, so the possibility that the knowledge to build ships capable of remaining at sea for many months wasn't lost must be considered. This seems especially likely for Hawaiians, Samoans, and other island-dwelling groups, and perhaps even Australians.

it would seem to be problematic on YEC to propose a similar idea given that the ice bridge is dated much earlier than 6000 or 4200 years ago

By whose dating? (Rhetorical.)
Always keep in mind that materialist "dates" are frequently inflated in order to accommodate their belief in "Common Descent" (i.e. the idea that humans are descended from non-human primates, who are in turn descended from fish, etc.). This applies not just to likely ice bridge(s), which would of course have existed not long after the Flood, but also to the civilizations themselves, sometimes in direct conflict with those people's own recorded histories.
As far as scale, don't forget that Noah's family started off as a mere eight people. It doesn't necessarily take a lot of people to give birth to a large civilization.

What evidence do we have that pre-colonial residents of the Americas had the technology of boating?

@LukeHill, one would think inhabitants of remote islands must have gotten there by boat originally, whether one believes YEC or not. That said, with respect to the Americas, the genetic evidence seems to favor population from Russia through Alaska, likely by "land". The point is that we shouldn't rule out boats "because ancient people were primitive".

I don't see any 'technology' to 'boating'. All one needs is a tree and an axe. The technology of flotation is provided in creation (water and wood). Answer up-voted +1.

@NigelJ, right; the means to do something and the knowledge how to do something aren't the same. Noah built the Ark, likely with his sons' help. Pre-flood people worked bronze and iron (Genesis 4:22), so that knowledge could have been retained also, and the relevant infrastructure doesn't take long to build. Writing was almost certainly retained, probably what mathematics they had as well, and I'd be very surprised if humans circa Babel weren't firing pottery.
